# Filling in Value for NA with tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to fill in a specific `NA` value with 'NY'. This is my approach:

```
data %>% 
  filter(is.na(State) & City == 'New York') %>%
  select(State) <- 'NY'
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
Error in data %>% filter(is.na(State) & City == "New York") %>% select(State) <- "NY" : 
could not find function "%>%<-"
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this :

```
data$State[is.na(data$State) & data$City == 'New York'] <- 'NY'
```

You can also use `replace` if you want to do this in `dplyr` pipe.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% mutate(State = replace(State, is.na(State) & City == 'New York', 'NY'))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
      mutate(State = case_when(is.na(State) & City == 'New York' ~ 'NY', 
            TRUE ~ State))
```